# What is the best approach when using SQLite3 from multiple module in the same global python application?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I currently develop a web application in python 2.7 that is build on a couple of module that I import in my main python application and call function from them. Almost all of these module are opening a connection to the same SQLite3 database and some of them are doing update or insert into table from time to time.

Sometime, I get database locked error when two or more module try to update the db at the same time. That lead me to questionning myself...

Am I doing the wrong thing opening and closing the connection to the database all the time or should I better to open it at the beginning of the program and close it at the end?

In this case, what would be the better way of sharing this connection between all my module?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite is not designed to handle concurrent accesses (especially write accesses).

Keeping the connection open is usually a good idea but this may depend on how often it is used.

If database accesses can happen from multiple threads it is useful to encapsulate all of them with the same `Lock` or `RLock`.

E.g. you can write a context manager for it, roughly so:

```
class ConnectionHolder:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.lock = RLock()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        return self.connection

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.lock.release()
```

Usage:

```
conn_holder = ConnectionHolder(connection) #Global or in an app-wide accessible object

...
with conn_holder as conn:
    conn.<do something>
    ...


<Don't do anything more with conn>
```

If `Lock` or `RLock` should be used depends on the use case. `Lock` may be slightly more efficient (but normally this isn't relevant) but `RLock` allows usage like e.g.

```
def getSomeData():
    with conn_holder as conn:
        <Retrieve data over conn and return it>


def changeSomeData():
    with conn_holder as conn:
        data = getSomeData()

        <Modify retrieved data and update database (saved against concurrent
         changes by the "with")>
```

where you can call `getSomeData()` either directly or indirectly through `changeSomeData()`.

(Well, depending on database mode (WAL-mode) you wouldn't need a lock for `getSomeData()` but there may be more complex situations where it is needed.)

Comment: Take a look at my answer and give me your comment please. Thanks!

Comment: @morpheus65535 What answer?

Comment: Sorry, it's been removed. I had to ask in another post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632288/sqlite3-context-manager-with-file-locking-in-python-2-7

Thanks!

Comment: @morpheus65535 I have added here some explanation about RLock vs. Lock

Comment: Thanks, I'll make another class for my SELECT.