# SQlite3 context manager with file locking in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

Is this the good way to do file locking with re-entrance in a context manager under Python 2.7? I just want to be sure the rlock() is going to be effective so I could get a multi-threaded application to use a single database file.

```
import sqlite3
import threading
import os

class ConnectionHolder:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.path = connection
        self.lock = threading.RLock()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(self.path)
        self.cursor = self.connection .cursor()
        return self.cursor


    def __exit__(self, exc_class, exc, traceback):
        self.connection .commit()
        self.connection .close()
        self.lock.release()

conn_holder = ConnectionHolder(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data/db/database.db'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with conn_holder as c:
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM 'sample_table'")
        result = c.fetchall()
        print result
```

Comment: IIUC SQLite should [take care ot this](https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) for you.

Comment: I got database locked error, that’s why I’m looking for other solution.

Comment: A lock that is private to the holder does not help. Anyway, you should just increase the busy timeout.

Comment: This post tell me different: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/82223446?noredirect=1

Comment: Increasing timeout seems like putting a bandaid. I’m not fixing problem, I just hope it won’t happen again...

Answer (score 0):

I finally fond in my code a place where I was running a long loop (about 2 minutes) before commiting. I correct this and, as @DB suggested, increase busy timeout to 30 seconds. Problem seem to be resolved. Thanks guys!